# How to solve Internal Server Error when integrating Swagger/OpenAPI

Tags: python, flask, swagger, openapi

a college student here trying to finish a confusing assignment at 4am.
The end goal should be to produce a centralized log server, where different systems can run a python script that sends all kinds of logs to this server.
I have to design an API for a centralized server where the logs can be stored.
So this is what I've started with:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from connexion import App

app = Flask(__name__)
connexion_app = App(__name__, specification_dir='./')
connexion_app.add_api("swagger.yml", arguments={'title': 'Centralized Log Server API'})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connexion_app.run(port=8000, server='uvicorn', debug=True)
```

swagger.yml:

```
openapi: 3.0.0

info:
  title: "Centralized Log Server API"
  description: "API for storing and managing log messages from various systems"
  version: "1.0.0"

servers:
  - url: "/api"

paths:
  /logs:
    get:
      operationId: "get_all_logs"
      tags:
        - "Logs"
      summary: "Retrieve a list of all log entries"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "Successfully retrieved log entries"

    post:
      operationId: "create_log"
      tags:
        - "Logs"
      summary: "Add a new log entry"
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/LogEntry"
      responses:
        "201":
          description: "Successfully created a new log entry"

  /logs/{system}:
    get:
      operationId: "get_logs_by_system"
      tags:
        - "Logs"
      summary: "Retrieve a list of log entries for a specific system or IP address"
      parameters:
        - name: "system"
          in: "path"
          required: true
          description: "System name or IP address"
          schema:
            type: "string"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "Successfully retrieved log entries for the specified system"

  /logs/date/{date}:
    get:
      operationId: "get_logs_by_date"
      tags:
        - "Logs"
      summary: "Retrieve a list of log entries for a specific date"
      parameters:
        - name: "date"
          in: "path"
          required: true
          description: "Date in the format YYYY-MM-DD"
          schema:
            type: "string"
            format: "date"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "Successfully retrieved log entries for the specified date"

  /logs/delete/{date}:
    delete:
      operationId: "delete_logs_by_date"
      tags:
        - "Logs"
      summary: "Delete all log entries before a specific date"
      parameters:
        - name: "date"
          in: "path"
          required: true
          description: "Date in the format YYYY-MM-DD"
          schema:
            type: "string"
            format: "date"
      responses:
        "204":
          description: "Successfully deleted log entries before the specified date"

  /logs/update/{log_id}:
    put:
      operationId: "update_log"
      tags:
        - "Logs"
      summary: "Update a log entry"
      parameters:
        - name: "log_id"
          in: "path"
          required: true
          description: "ID of the log entry to update"
          schema:
            type: "string"
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/LogEntry"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "Successfully updated the log entry"

components:
  schemas:
    LogEntry:
      type: "object"
      properties:
        system:
          type: "string"
          description: "System name or IP address"
        timestamp:
          type: "string"
          format: "date-time"
          description: "Date & time of the log entry"
        level:
          type: "string"
          description: "Log entry level (e.g., informational, warning, error)"
        message:
          type: "string"
          description: "The actual log entry message"
        file:
          type: "string"
          description: "Complete directory & filename the message applies to"
      required:
        - system
        - timestamp
        - level
        - message
```

And my home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Log Viewer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Log Viewer</h1>
    
    <!-- Display logs here -->
    <ul id="logList"></ul>

    <script>
        // Fetch and display logs using JavaScript
        async function fetchLogs() {
            const response = await fetch('/api/logs');
            const logs = await response.json();

            const logList = document.getElementById('logList');
            logList.innerHTML = '';

            logs.forEach(log => {
                const listItem = document.createElement('li');
                listItem.textContent = `${log.timestamp} - ${log.level}: ${log.message}`;
                logList.appendChild(listItem);
            });
        }

        // Call fetchLogs on page load
        fetchLogs();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

backup.py (the file that will send the log entries):

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

def get_timestamp():
    return datetime.now().strftime(("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

LOG_ENTRIES = {
    "System1": {
        "system": "System1",
        "timestamp": get_timestamp(),
        "level": "info",
        "message": "Backup successful",
        "file": "/path/to/file1.txt",
    },
    "System2": {
        "system": "System2",
        "timestamp": get_timestamp(),
        "level": "warning",
        "message": "Backup failed",
        "file": "/path/to/file2.txt",
    },
    "System3": {
        "system": "System3",
        "timestamp": get_timestamp(),
        "level": "error",
        "message": "Critical error during backup",
        "file": "/path/to/file3.txt",
    }
}

def send_log_entries():
    for system, log_entry in LOG_ENTRIES.items():
        try:
            response = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/logs', json=log_entry)
            response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an HTTPError for bad responses
            print(f"Log entry for {system} sent successfully.")
        except requests.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error sending log entry for {system}: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    send_log_entries()
```

After running this command to run the app.py file:

> python3 -m uvicorn app:app --reload

and i browse to 127.0.0.1 I get a webpage stating 'internal server error'
on the terminal I see this error:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\said4\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\httptools_impl.py", line 426, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "C:\Users\said4\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\said4\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\asgi2.py", line 16, in __call__
    instance = self.app(scope)
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'start_response'
INFO:     127.0.0.1:32561 - "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
```

I get the same error when running the backup.py file. I've been trying to debug this for the past week, but i don't seem intelligent enough to find a solution. Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: it doesnt look like you have any routes for flask (`app = flask.Flask(...)`) when you call `uvicorn app:app` that is the app you are referencing ... perhaps you want `uvicorn app:connexion_app `

Comment: @JoranBeasley Okay so I've been able to solve the problem by running the application with just python3 app.py. And now I can finally visit the webpage. But every time I run backup.py, I get this error: 'Error sending log entry for System3: 405 Client Error: METHOD NOT ALLOWED for url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/logs'